# Vim: regex to match words inside angle brackets?

Tags: regex, vim

I want to match words inside angle brackets (html tags):

```
<MatchedWord></MartchedWord>
```

This is what I have so far:

```
/\v\<\w+\>
```

The problem is that it matches the `<>` too and the `/`.

How to do it so it only matches the word?

Comment: Those are angle brackets, not square brackets! These are square brackets: `[]`

Comment: @DevonParsons OK, fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assert matching before and after text without including that in the match via Vim's special `\zs` (match start) and `\ze` (match end) atoms:

```
/<\/\?\zs\w\+\ze\/\?>
```

I've included an optional (`\?`) slash on both side (e.g. `</this>` and `<this/>`. Also note that `\w\+` isn't a completely correct expression for XML or HTML tags (but it can be a good-enough approximation, depending on your data).

#### Alternative

For most other regular expression engines, you need to use *lookbehind* and *lookahead* to achieve this. Vim has those, too (`\@<=` and `\@=`), but the syntax is more awkward, and the matching performance may be poorer.

Comment: that seems to match all `<`'s

Comment: I haven't used Vim for RegEx, how are capturing groups handled. My solution would be the simplest using capturing groups

Comment: @mgamba: If you type this, the `/` need to be escaped; I've added that!

Comment: @Jeanno: Capturing groups are for _replacement_ (with `:substitute`); they don't help with pure searching.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to escape angle brackets (square brackets are []) since they are not special characters. You can use capturing groups

```
<\/?(.+)>
```

Answer (score 1):

In a non-vim environment, this is achieved using positive lookbehind and lookahead as such:

```
/(?<=<).*?(?=>)/
```

This matches the following:

```
<test>         // test
</content>     // /content
<div id="box"> // div id="box"
<div id="lt>"> // div id="lt
```

So as you can see by the final example it's not perfect, but you are using regex on html so [you get what you pay for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3512592)

[See the regex in action](https://regex101.com/r/xC9jX1/1)

Comment: Obviously the OP is asking specifically for VIM, this answer is included for future readers.

Comment: Vim also has positive lookbehind and lookahead: `\(<\)\@<=.*\(>\)\@=`

Comment: @Ben I know that Vim has lookahead and lookbehind, this answer is not about Vim